# Shell script with jar file at the end

Tags: java, shell, jar

I download an [archive file](http://superbe.am/download/5173). In the archive there will be a file that has a `.sh`. extension. When I opened that file with VI I found the below code in the beginning of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt 0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
java=java
if test -n "$JAVA_HOME"; then
    java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
exec "$java" $java_args -jar $MYSELF "$@"
exit 1
```

I can run the jar by doing `java -jar file` or `./file'.

Can someone explain me what is going on? How can you create such file?

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised that that works. I thought a JAR file was just a ZIP file with a different extension, and a ZIP needs to start with a particular header. Can you give a link to the download?

Comment: What is the output of the command `file <jar-file-name>` ?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca it print data. I added a link to the file if you want to test it

Comment: It is some kind of start-up script, check what kind of parameters are passed to it.

Comment: @Thomas Note my comment in the accepted answer; in brief, Zip files ignore a certain amount of data at the beginning of the file before a valid Zip header, but this can be finicky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try by yourself the following commands. Start creating a normal jar file with any content, or use someone you have. I will name it "myjar.jar"

Next, create a file "hello.sh" with content:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec echo hello
```

now, add this file at start of a new jar file:

```
cat hello.sh myjar.jar > mytrick.jar
chmod 700 mytrick.jar
```

And finally, the interesting part, type:

```
./mytrick.jar
jar -tf mytrick.jar
unzip mytrick.jar
```

in other words, usually jar/unzip skips any content until their own header. Moreover, a shell script "ends" in a line who call "exec" (because shell interpreter is replace at this point by the command in the exec line).

However, this trick is based in a behaviour of jar/unzip probably out of standards. Note, by example, that this statement fails (has no effects):

```
jar -xf mytrick.jar
```

Comment: If you receive errors about a corrupt Jar file, try adding empty lines to the end of the shell script.  This can be important to trick the Zip decoder into skipping over the script header.

Answer (score 3):

If the file after extracting the tar file is *start-superbeam.sh* try doing `chmod +x start-superbeam.sh && ./start-superbeam.sh` or `/bin/sh ./start-superbeam.sh`.

If the program has arguments, supply them after at the end. It will run java on that the superbeam.sh which as a jar file at the end.

If you need special java parameters set such as for memory size, you would set them in the environment variable `java_args`.

As for what's going on this is a shell script with a jar file at the end of it after the `exit`. To quote from [ReallyExecutable Jars](http://skife.org/java/unix/2011/06/20/really_executable_jars.html):

> There has long been a hack known in some circles, but not widely
>   known, to make jars really executable, in the chmod +x sense. The hack
>   takes advantage of the fact that jar files are zip files, and zip
>   files allow arbitrary cruft to be prepended to the zip file itself
>   (this is how self-extracting zip files work).

As for how to create, see the accepted answer or the link.

Comment: I would have accepted your answer if you have added the details that are given in the article you link.